# XMLHttpRequest readyState stops on 1

Tags: javascript

I'm having some problems with this code I've done:

```
function server_status() {
    setInterval(function(){
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', 'http://mcapi.sweetcode.de/api/v2/?info&ip=jogar.millenarycraft.com', true);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = new function(){
            document.getElementById("server_counter").innerHTML = 'ReadyState: ' + xhr.readyState;
            if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                if(data.status){
                    document.getElementById("server_counter").innerHTML = '<span>Jogadores online: <span style="color:#FD7C00;">' + data.player.online + '</span></span>';
                }else{
                    document.getElementById("server_counter").innerHTML = '<span style="color:#FD7C00;">Servidor offline!</span>';
                }
            }
        }
        xhr.send();
    }, 1000);
}
```

It is inside a script tag and work as well, but I'm having problems just from  `document.getElementById("server_counter").innerHTML = 'ReadyState: ' + xhr.readyState;` on. I noticed that the `readystate` stops on 1 and I don't know why! Can anyone help me?

PS: And the problem is not with the url, because I did a PHP version and it worked very well. I just want to use JavaScript because I need to update the value without refreshing the page in a certain time.

Comment: There is absolutely *zero* jQuery in your code.

Comment: *" I just want to use JQUERY because I need to update the value without refreshing the page in a certain time."* That doesn't have anything to do with jQuery. What you're describing is making an XHR request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have an unintended error:

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = new function(){
```

Change to:

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
```

`new` should most certainly not be there. I think as it is your function is called once before you've called `xhr.send()`, hence `xhr.readyState` is `1`.

Comment: +1 Good catch. The function is being invoked immediately, and an object is returned.